# Extract only name from the outlook email string using python 2.7 & Regex utility. i have mentioned my best regex trials & its output for reference

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Input:-

```
x = 'William John <William.John@InfoTechservices.com>; C S N Murphy <CSN.Murphy@InfoTechservices.com>; Raja Rahim<Rahim.Raja@InfoTechservices.com>'
```

Expected Output:-

```
y = ['William John','C S N Murphy','Raja Rahim']
```

Failed Trials :-

```
Input- re.findall(r"; (.*?)<",x)
Output- ['C S N Murphy ', 'Raja Rahim']
Comment: "William John" is missing & space after Murphy.

Input- re.findall("(\w+.\w+).<",x)
Output-['William John', 'N Murphy', 'Raja Rahi']
Comment: "C S " is missing & also "m" is missing in Rahim.
```

I tried a lot but i could not able to make it. I am a python learner So please help me to figure out exact output.
Thank You Very Much in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting and comprehension instead:

```
s = "William John <William.John@InfoTechservices.com>; C S N Murphy <CSN.Murphy@InfoTechservices.com>; Raja Rahim<Rahim.Raja@InfoTechservices.com>"
print([x.split("<")[0].strip() for x in s.split("; ")])
# => ['William John', 'C S N Murphy', 'Raja Rahim']
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/i531fP)

A regex that can help:

```
([^<]+)<[^<]*>(?:;\s*)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO9oY5/1) and an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/74OgOq):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([^<]+)<[^<]*>(?:;\s*)?')
test_str = "William John <William.John@InfoTechservices.com>; C S N Murphy <CSN.Murphy@InfoTechservices.com>; Raja Rahim<Rahim.Raja@InfoTechservices.com>"
print(p.findall(test_str)) # => ['William John ', 'C S N Murphy ', 'Raja Rahim']
```

The pattern should be used with `re.findall` as it contains one capturing group whose value will be output to the resulting list. The pattern matches:

- `([^<]+)` - Group 1 matching 1+ characters other than `<`
- `<` - an opening angle bracket
- `[^<]*` - 0+ characters other than `<`
- `>` - a closing angle bracket
- `(?:;\s*)?` - an optional group (`(?:...)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of a sequence) matching `;` followed with 0+ whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am looking for a solution with Regex only. But once again thanks for your efforts.

Comment: As you wish, but the string you have seems to have a fixed format, no need using regex in such cases. Really.